# Synchronize FBA Users (ASPNET Membership Databse in SQL Server) in User Profile Service

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service, forms-authentication

I have FBA configured in a web application (SharePoint 2013) with ASPNET Membership Database in SQL Server.

Now I need to have FBA users (SQL - Membership Database users) synchronized in User Profile Service. Please let me know if there is any way to avail this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

BCS will only append to existing profiles, so you will not be able to leverage it. Instead, you're going to have to look at 3rd party, custom code, or full fledged Forefront Identity Manager.

I wrote code to do basic imports from LDAP (AD LDS) and it isn't terribly difficult.

Comment: Can you enlighten us on what kind of "basic code" you wrote. C#, powershell? how would you go about doing that?

Comment: It's in the form of a timer job, you can take a look at it here - https://github.com/Nauplius/SharePoint-LDAP-FBA/blob/master/Nauplius.ADLDS.UserProfiles/Nauplius.ADLDS.UserProfiles/Program.cs.

Answer (score 0):

Use Business Connectivity Service(BCS) application to synchronize your membership DB with User profile  service.

[A useful link](http://www.slideshare.net/pstorkoh/ups-tips-and-troubleshooting)